# How do a I set up a billing service that allow people to authorize automated billing?

Tags: web-services, recurring-billing

I want to start up a charity website that must provide a way for people to allow some type of automated billing system. They should have the ability to authorize it on my website without having to talk the banks directly. At the end of the month, they do not need to worry about paying off the bill or anything ... its just automatically handled by the bank.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paypal supplies infrastructure that seems to enable what your want. You probably do not want to handle both the security/privacy implications and working with the banks yourself anyway.